# How to read a .csv file with shell command?

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I have a .csv file which I need to extract values from. It is formatted like this :

> First line of the file (no data)
>
> 1;Jack;Daniels;Madrid;484016;
>
> 2;Alice;Morgan;London;564127;
>
> etc...

I would need a shell command that read all lines of a specific column within a .csv, compare each with a string and return a value whenever it finds a matching line. In Java i would define it something like :

```
> boolean findMatchInCSV(String valueToFind, int colNumber, String
> colSeparator)
```

The separator between columns may indeed change that is why I would like a something quite generic if possible :)

But **I need it as a shell command**, is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep "my_string" file |awk -F ";" '{print $5}'
```

or

```
awk -F ";" '/my_string/ {print $5}' file
```

For 2nd column:

```
awk -F ";" '$2 ~ /my_string/ {print $5}' file
```

For exact matching:

```
awk -F ";" '$2 == "my_string" {print $5}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for those solutions :)

Answer (score 4):

> I would need a shell command that read all lines

```
cat 1.csv                         # read the file
```

> of a specific column within a .csv

```
cat 1.csv | cut -f5 -d';'         # keep only the field #5 (use ';' as separator)
```

> compare each with a string

```
# keep only the row where the value of the field is exactly 'foo'
cat 1.csv | cut -f5 -d';' | grep '^foo$'
```

> return a value whenever it finds a matching line.

This last one request is unclear.

The code above displays the searched string (`foo`) once for each row where it is the value of column #5 (start counting from 1). The columns are separated by `;`.

**Unfortunately, it doesn't handle quoted strings.** If the value in any field contains the separator (`;`), the CSV format allows enclosing the field value into double quotes (`"`) to prevent the separator character be interpreted as a separator (forcing its literal value).

Comment: Thanks, with your explanation I now understand all the steps, the command is way easier than I thought it would be :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for something like

```
FILE=data.csv
VALUE="$1"
COLNUM=$2
IFS="$3"

while read -r -a myArray
do
    if "$myArray[$COLNUM]"=="$VALUE"; then
        exit 0
    fi
done < tail -n +2 $FILE

exit 1
```